# RecyclerView overscrollmode

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use the windowmanager to add a recyclerview. And in the xml file, I set the recyclerview overscrollmode to never.
I hope the scrollbar shows. The code as below.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/expand_list_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbarSize="2dp"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/white"
    android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/expand_list_scroll_bar"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

When the android:overScrollMode set never. The scrollbars disappears too. I don't know why.Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can try set  android:fadeScrollbars="false",
and then The length of the RecycleView is longer than the parent layout